# How to implement a vertical and horizontal scroll bar in WinForms when using paint?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my code I draw a rectangle and usually the rectangle is too large for the screen, even when maximised. I have set the form property `AutoScroll` to true and this doesn't seem to do anything. There won't be anything else on my form except the rectangle painting, how can I implement a vertical and horizontal scroll?

```
 PrintingDesignForm form = new PrintingDesignForm();

        form.Paint += (se, pe) => {
            var r = new Rectangle(parameters.RectangleXPosition, parameters.RectangleYPosition, (int)Math.Ceiling(parameters.RectangleWidth) * 72, (int)Math.Ceiling(parameters.RectangleLength) * 72);

            var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 204));

            pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, r);
            using (var pen = new Pen(brush.Color, 2))
                pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, r);
        };

        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        form.Show();
```

Comment: You also need to set the AutoScrollMinsize to a suitable value, ie one that is large enough to hold your drawing. You should know that when drawing..

Comment: @TaW By default the AutoScrollMinsize property is set to 0,0. Doesn't this mean that it should automatically scroll?

Comment: No. Unless your conrtol is smaller than (0,0) ;-) - You can read the meanig as how much space the scrollbars must provide.

Comment: Ah I see. This worked, although it made the rectangle pretty choppy. But that's another issue I'll look into. If you want to put your suggestion into an answer, I'll happily select it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `AutoScroll = true` on a `Control/Form`  alone will only ensure that all `Controls` you **add/nest** to the parent will either show or can be reached by the scrollbars which will show up as needed.

**This doesn't do anything for stuff you draw.**

To make the drawing scrollable you need to set the `AutoScrollMinSize` to large enough values.

If you don't know in advance then at least while drawing you should be able to determine them from your data.

Answer (score 0):

In Form Properties Set

> AutoScroll = True